# Timeline of Question post, Question Edits, Answer and Answer Edits

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, timeline

There was quite some confusion (apparently due to my contribution as well) for [Replace a substring in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634723/string-operation-in-c) as to certain answers which did not "seem" to address the question (but had up-votes). Hence I down-voted some of them, only to later realize that the question was edited after these down-voted answers were posted. Then I had to up-vote them back after requesting each answer to be edited to enable me to up-vote them.

Is there a better way (visual or otherwise) to check the timeline of the question post, answers, question edits and answer edits to avoid making my mistake again? Looking at the last edited time of the post would definitely require some patience.

If not, I believe this would be a great addition to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You upvoted answers that didn't address the question anymore? ...why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question does have a [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7634723/timeline) that orders events on the question chronologically, which may be more of what you were looking for.

To get to it, you have to construct the link manually for each post, or install a userscript that adds such links. I work on [one that does that](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an), and there are a few others [listed on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) for this purpose as well.

Comment: That's great! I guess this may need some tweaks like highlighting the question edits to distinguish them apart from the answer edits. But a good approach. Thank you, I will try the userscript.