# What is the active link for on the right side of a question

Tags: discussion, questions, last-activity

If I go to a question like this one:

[What is the instanceof operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449254/what-is-the-instanceof-operator-in-javascript)

On the right hand side there are some stats that say the number of views, etc.  One of the stats says "active" with a value as a hyperlink.  What purpose does this serve?

If I click this hyperlink the page flickers and nothing else happens.  Is this meant to be a clickable link?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"active" refers to question activity that may cause it to be bumped to the front page, which may be one of the following things (among [others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-my-question-to-be-bumped)):

- The question was posted (in which case, date active is the same as date asked)
- An answer was posted
- The question, or one of its answers, was edited
- A bounty was started

The value links to the last-active item on the question page (indicated by a `?lastactivity` query string in the link). For example, if a new answer was posted or edited, clicking this link takes you directly to that answer. If the last activity was on the question itself, it takes you back to the question.

Comment: Okay that could be why clicking it is just taking me back to the question then.

Comment: @JonH If it doesn't scroll to something that visibly has a current timestamp that's probably because the activity was a now-deleted post (e.g. a spam answer on an old question).