# Who can change someone's accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I am talking about following question

[Fill SVG only if existing fill colour is certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590985/fill-svg-only-if-existing-fill-colour-is-certain-value/18596668#18596668)

I am quite sure that the OP had accepted my answer (you can see his comment underneath my answer) but after sometime the accepted answer has been changed and now Robert Longson's answer has been accepted.

Now I want to know who has changed this and should not I get a notification with a reason?

Can I get a question specific summary?

Comment: Maybe by "question specific summary" you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18590985/timeline)?

Comment: @bfavaretto Woah, is there a way to easily see a timeline like this for any question? Or do you have to edit the URL every time?

Comment: @p.s.w.g There's no link that I know of, you have to edit the URL.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - It's an expensive query, and that level of detail is not generally necessary, so it's a "hidden" feature.

Comment: @p.s.w.g it was [suggested and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/152859) to add such link, just edit the URL manually by changing "/questions" to "/posts" and adding "/timeline" after the ID.

Comment: @bfavaretto this(http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18590985/timeline) is exactly what i want and now i think i know how to get it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The question asker can change the accepted answer to their question at their own discretion, or even unaccept an answer without reaccepting. You already get a "notification" by way of losing the 15 rep you were previously awarded with the acceptance, but the asker isn't obliged to tell you their reason for accepting another answer over yours.

No idea what you mean by "question specific summary".

Comment: it is not about reputation it is just you should get atleast a notification

Comment: @Dhaval: You don't get a notification when your answer is accepted, so why should you get a notification when your answer is unaccepted?

Comment: Unaccepts already appear in your reputation history.

Comment: @Dhaval - Why? Of what use would that information be to you?

Comment: @Dhaval - Notifications on accepted answers would be a horrible idea. Imagine how full Jon Skeets inbox would be :O

Comment: @JoshMein i got your idea and you are right .. i thought at my level but in broad you are right ...

Comment: User vote should be able to re-accept an answer. There are so many cases on this website where a mediocre answer is accepted above a very good one below