# Add 'sequential activity of thread' convenience

Tags: feature-request, last-activity

At the moment, if I want to look at the activity of a thread I've already read (new Answers, new Comments, new Answer/Question edits), I have to go through a tedious process. Luckily, we got a *lastactivity* button, but that only shows the latest activity:

[image]

By *sequential activity*, I mean a list of links sorted by latest activity first.

The reason I want this feature is because I often want to know what activity I missed. In my case, this is on threads I've Starred, in which I don't wanna miss a thing. It's easy to miss stuff when relying on *lastactivity*, especially on busy and/or large threads.

---

UPDATE: Good to know [such a feature exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64522), but  it would nice if it was easily accessible. An example would be the following, where *history* links to that activity:

```
active: 8 months ago (history)
```

Comment: `/posts/<postid>/timeline` give you what you want?

Comment: You already can sort the answers by last activity instead the default sort by votes.

Comment: Sort the page by activity then..

Comment: @MartijnPieters that doesn't do Comments

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64522/212576

Answer (score 2):

What we really need is a button that will call up the timeline view instead of having to manually type in the url for it.  A good explanation of what is shown there would also be nice.

Comment: True, but it [was declined already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/152859). :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks, I've bountied that.

Comment: Lost cause if you ask me, I tried back in April and other user in May both to no avail. Shog likely stick to his opinion and won't budge. :/

Comment: I agree, but I'm used to chasing lost causes.

Comment: Fair enough. Did it ever work out?

Comment: Well we got them to eventually compromise on seeing your own deleted questions.