# Shouldn't the timeline page be only available for members with the Established Users privilege?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, timeline

I currently have 251 reputation, thus I do not have the `Established User` privilege.

But I do have access to the timeline of a post, which already gives me access to one of the two perks of being an [established user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user).

> They may view the vote counts on posts

And I even get mroe details, since I would know exactly, when was the question and each of its asnwer downvoted and upvoted.

For example, [this is the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/227571/timeline) of this question.

Answer (score 10):

The "view vote count" privileges is less about restricting access to the specific vote counts and more about limiting load on the servers.

From Jeff's answer on [Show Total Votes (or Up/Down Votes)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes/1007#1007)

> The total vote count (score) is denormalized, but the individual up/down vote counts are not.
>
> So to display it on every post would incur 2 vote table queries * number of visible questions / answers. Our DB is fast, but the vote table is pretty massive, and not doing a query is always faster than doing it.

So ultimately, the only reason it is a privilege is because it is expensive to do.  The timeline page can be cached so it is less expensive and does not need to be a privilege, which is why you can access it without achieving a specific rep level.

Comment: Additionally I don't think a lot of people know of that page? It's the first time I've seen it. Or have I missed an obvious link all these years?

Comment: @Stijn it's not linked at all, although I recall seeing a user script floating around here once before to add it client side.

Comment: @Stijn [here's the post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) I was thinking of.  Shog links a script to add it in his answer.

Comment: The up/down counts are denormalised now.

Comment: @JanDvorak really?  I missed that, which sort of blows the argument out of the water.  I can't find a reference to that change

Comment: The timeline page is also not linked from anywhere. It's effectively a power-user route. Nothing on it is *secret* per se, and this part of the  "Established User" privilege is more about convenience and ease of access to the voting breakdown than anything else.