# Show votes count history in editing (revisions) history

Tags: feature-request, edits, voting, revisions-list

We should show near every revision how many votes the post had at the time of publishing that revision.

It can be interesting to see, for example, that, if a question had some features that led to gaining downvotes; later the author edited it, and added some other features. Now the post has many downvotes, but we do not know why it has gained them, whether because of the later-added features, or whether it had many downvotes before them already.

Answer (score 7):

That's what the [timeline (described near the end of post)](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/76569) is for, more or less, although it doesn't have a resolution better than a single day. This may be for the best: my hunch is that showing exact scores for every revision is more likely to expose individual voting patterns, which is a pretty big no-no. There's a feature request to [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post), which would make this more visible.

Comment: There is a nice script to add a "timeline" link to every question - [View Post Timeline](http://stackapps.com/q/4148) - very useful ;)