# "bumped by community user" is not attributed to Community in question's timeline

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-user, bump, timeline

I just noticed in [the timeline of a question](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/58396/timeline) that was bumped by Community, that the event is not attributed to [Community](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) at all:

> [image]

Other actions (e.g. anonymous edits) are attributed to Community just fine.

In case this is an oversight, can it please be fixed? Or if on purpose, can this event please be attributed to Community user for the sake of consistency?

Comment: +1 for the sad face :(

Comment: In that case, `"bumped by community user"` should also be reduced to `bumped` only, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh interesting point, not sure about it though. (e.g. such event can be done *only* by Community, so omitting it might lead people to think ordinary users can cause such event)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Community bump attribution has now been corrected, as part of the recent [upgrade for post timelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/51).