# Why doesn't this question show a vote to close?

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-close, specific-question

I voted to close a question. Later, I was brought back to the question by a comment and noticed that it doesn't show any votes to close. So I clicked the link, only to see that it said I'd already voted to close the question.

Why would a question not show any votes to close if I'd already cast one?

(The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192130/ajax-request-wont-loop-properly), but let's not meta-effect it, it's not in any way egregious or problematic. I'm just curious what happened.)

Comment: The timeline shows it was closed then reopened... So your vote took effect and was used up and there's currently no active close votes.

Comment: see the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42192130/timeline)

Comment: @JonClements - Thanks, I figured it was something like that, but I keep forgetting how to access the timeline.

Comment: If you're into userscripts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180568/158100 or https://gist.github.com/cauerego/d6382a8952663bb7753f

Comment: @rene: I am, and: ***Nice!***

Answer (score 7):

You can see the full timeline of things that have happened to a question by taking the post number (42192130, in this case), and filling it into:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/{post_number}/timeline
```

So in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42192130/timeline, which shows that the question was closed after my close vote, and then reopened. So later when I'm viewing it, I don't see a pending close vote (mine was "used" when it was originally closed), but I can't vote to close, either, because you can't vote to close when you've already done so.

(The link above works with answers, too.)

---

Thank you [Jon Clements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/191185/jon-clements) and [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene).