# Timeline duplicate list edited, suggest improvement

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, timeline

Thank you for the introducing the timeline. It gives you a great overview about what happened in a post.

I would suggest to list the full urls of the duplicate targets when the dupe list is edited or when a post is closed as a duplicate.

Currently, when the duplicate list is edited, all we see is:

[image]

When a post is closed, it merely gives the "Duplicate" reason, and doesn't include the dupe targets:

[image]

Could we display links/urls here?

Comment: For the record: the feature isn't new. It was simply hidden. In the past we got there by modifying the URL.

Comment: @mast Not quite; it's been revamped too. Shog put a lot into it right before he was dropped like a rock. Read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/155739).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timeline display for closed-duplicate rows has been updated:

- Duplicate List Edited rows now shows the linked titles of the before/after posts (like on the revision history)
- Duplicate rows now links to the duplicate post