# Add some line breaks in the "duplicate list edited" message in the timeline and revision history

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, revisions-list, timeline, dupehammer

When a gold badge user or a moderator edits the duplicate list of a question, it now [properly shows the new list's links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342322/timeline-duplicate-list-edited-suggest-improvement) in the timeline.

This change is great, but I think we can do even better.

Currently, it's rather difficult to see the previous list and the new list, as there are no line breaks separating the previous list revision and the new list. Additionally, when the duplicate list is more than one link long, there is only a comma separating the links.

Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Could we insert some line breaks in here in the name of readability? Namely after "duplicates list edited from:", "to:", and after every link?

I recognize that this makes this particular entry in the timeline rather space-consuming, but a duplicate list edit is a pretty rare event on its own. When it does happen, I feel this change will greatly improve readability.

Here's a screenshot of my proposed format:

[image]

Glorfindel pointed out that the revision entry for a dupe list edit doesn't look much better, and is an exact copy of the timeline's message:

[image]

Could we apply this change here as well? After tossing some line breaks into the message, it looks quite a bit cleaner.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I guess I'm known for obscuring things :P The revision list doesn't look much better: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/347766/revisions

Comment: @Glorfindel Looks like an exact copy of the message in the timeline. I wonder if we could apply this change to both entries?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. FWIW, thanks to your report, I spotted [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347805/295232) ...

Comment: Related/duplicate (your post is slightly older, but the other post has a much higher score): [Please improve the design for "duplicates list edited" in post revisions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353786/335251)

Comment: @V2Blast Only because Sam totally abused his mod privileges to migrate it here from Meta SO and double-dipped on the votes! >:( (kidding of course, I'd love some exposure for this in any way shape or form.)

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate to keep future activity about this in one spot. As V2Blast indicated, the dupe has much more support, so we should probably forward future visitors there.

Answer (score 3):

My [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) converts the "duplicate list edited" entry in question revision history pages into two lists.

This makes it clearer which links were added/removed, as well as the new sort order (if it was re-ordered):

[image: screenshot of updated design]