# Please improve the design for "duplicates list edited" in post revisions page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, duplicate-questions, revisions-list

Ever since the release of the feature that allowed users with the dupe/gold hammer privilege to **edit a question's duplicate list**, there hasn't been any improvement to how it is displayed in the post revisions page.

I'm referring to this (*example screenshot*):

[image: screenshot of current design]

This makes it difficult to see at a glance,

- which links were removed
- which links were added
- and if the list was re-ordered

Comment: Related: [Add some line breaks in the “duplicate list edited” message in the timeline and revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347801/289905).

Comment: Funny how this is in the SO Hot meta Posts, and then links you here...

Comment: @Luuklag it was migrated from MSO.

Comment: @Braiam I saw that, but funny that it was still a HMP on SO. I know we should blame caching for that, but perhaps this should be a special case.

Comment: @SebastianSimon: BTW, that question has now been closed (by its author) as a duplicate of this one (since it's basically the exact same issue and suggested solution).

Answer (score 55):

I propose that the list be modified to something similar to what my [ReduceClutter userscript](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) already implements, and it is clearer which link was removed/added, and the new sort order (if it was re-ordered):

[image: screenshot of updated design]

Comment: Excellent request and idea; I might even suggest to go further and highlight the whole line in light red or light green, like GitHub diffs.

Comment: And while they're implementing this, they can make the "dialog box" where you do this editing responsive. I hate how it runs off my small screen, I can't pan left to see the buttons.