# Remove 'show timeline' from the mod menu

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, timeline

With the [post timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/295232) now available for everybody via the clock icon under the vote buttons, it can be removed from the mod menu. That list is already quite long, so fewer options is better.

[image]

Comment: The review history is also visible from the timeline right?

Comment: That leads to a separate moderator-only page. (Not a very useful one, I'll admit.)

Comment: *Very* useful! Please do not get rid of the "review history" page!

Comment: @CodyGray really? There's only one column I can't find anywhere else? Or is the timeline to crowded to be useful for certain posts and this one works better for you?

Comment: The latter. (I personally hate the timeline view and prefer the revision history because it's much less noisy. I only use the timeline if I need something that only it contains.) And also, this dedicated "review history" page is super convenient for scripts to scrape, in particular, one that pulls the review history out into a button in the sidebar under the timeline button, which I use for checking whether a post with pending NAA/VLQ flags was reviewed correctly by previous reviewers.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the clarification - I have no doubt the situation on SO is different from many other sites :)